# JavaScript - get substrings from complex string (name and units from "some metric [some unit]")

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the most elegant JavaScript/jQuery solution to split a complex string with a **name part** and a **units part** into two substrings, like so?

Input:

```
var source = "some metric (example) [some unit]";
```

Desired result:

```
var name = "some metric (example)"; //note - no trailing space
var units = "some unit";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split on the `[` bracket, then trim both parts to make sure there's no leading or trailing spaces, and remove the `]` bracket

```js
var source = "some metric (example) [some unit]";

var [name, units] = source.replace(']','').split(' [').map(x=>x.trim());

console.log(name);
console.log(units);
```

Answer (score 2):

I could do it like this:

```
var parts = source.split('[');
var name = parts[0];
var units = parts[1].substring(0, parts[1].length - 1);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nEX6Q/)**

Answer (score 2):

`String.prototype.lastIndexOf` with one of the *trim* functions.

```
var source = "some metric (example) [some unit]",
    i = source.lastIndexOf('['),
    name = $.trim(source.slice(0, i)),      // "some metric (example)"
    unit = $.trim(source.slice(i + 1, -1)); // "some unit"
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest regex which matches is probably

```
(.*)\s\[(.*?)\]
```

Defined as

- A numbered capture group (any character)
- whitespace
- Literal '['
- A numbereed capture group (any character as few as possible)
- Literal ']'

Javascript code

```
var regex = /(.*)\s\[(.*?)\]/;
var input = "some metric (example) [some unit]";
var result = regex.exec(input);
console.log(result[1])
console.log(result[2])
```

Result:

```
some metric (example)
some unit
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/2YNQM/